# Split-Path for splitting out a folder name

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am working on Powershell code... I have most of it written... I have one complication I can't figure out.   Part of my file directory is the year.   So basically I want to do a get-date to check current year...  and compare it with the date in the folder … i.e. get-date shows 2019 … folder name is 2019...  great.... we got a match... do this... otherwise I want to crate a folder name current year +1.

That's the whole plan … but taking it to step-one...  how do I isolate just the year folder name out so then I can compare it to the get-year?

Comment: Then please show the code you're working on. BTW your dot key seems to bounce heavily. Hint: `if ($folder.BaseName -match (Get-Date).Year){...}else{...}`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean that my dot key seems to bounce heavily.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a path like `C:\some\folder\2019` you can check the folder name against the current year like this:

```bsh
$dir = 'C:\some\folder\2019'

$year = (Get-Date).Year
if ("$year" -eq (Split-Path $dir -Leaf)) {
    # do something
} else {
    $parent = Split-Path $dir -Parent
    $newdir = Join-Path $parent ($year + 1)
    New-Item $newdir -Type Directory | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: Hey... thank you so very much... this appears that this would work.  My question is, and as an entry-level script writer I'm sure I'm over-reaching here...  I want to create a script that doesn't care what year it is.  It's purely, does $dir = c:\some\folder\*  match current year or not.  While the code you offers works for this year, next year it'd have to be (easily) reprogrammed.  Is there a way to do this that does  a current year check regardless of what current year is?

Comment: @BipBopMcKay What makes you believe the code I posted would not already do what you're asking?

Comment: great question.  Again, pointing out that I'm a novice incase this is stupid... LOL  I ask because it goes to the 2019 folder.   If I read that code right, it will always go to 2019 folder... will this code still work in 2020 to check if current year is 2020 or 2021?

Comment: @BipBopMcKay `Get-Date` always returns the current date and time. The `Year` property of that value will always be the current year.

Comment: Thank you.  I do understand that part, but that's not the part of the equation I see the problem with.   I'll do my best to explain the scenario …  we have a folder structure where we keep records of everything dating back to 2015.  Obviously, 2019 we're using the 2019 folder, 2020, we'll use the 2020 folder,  I need the code to keep up with the date changes of file names every year, match it to current year to see if the user is creating a new January folder for next year (create a folder for current year +1)... or if it's already "next year" (create a folder for current year)

Comment: If that's what you're aiming for: why not simply check if a folder for the current year already exists, and create it otherwise? Why the need to create one for next year? Another option would be to have the users use a folder "current" all of the time and rename "current" to `(Get-Date).Year - 1` when the year changes.

Comment: oooh …  that is an easier way to accomplish that!  Yeah, my entire code copies over last month, renames it to the next month, and removes all files but keeps folder structure.  It all works.  January creates a wrinkle in that a new previous folder (year) needs to be created to copy over last year's December to continue my script as written.  I suppose I could just code in an ask if this is the next year yet or not.. but thought it would be better if the script knows without asking.

Comment: I'm already doing part of your second suggestion...  `$*BuildsRootPath = "***"
$oldMonth = "01 - January"
$year = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y"
$newMonth = "$*BuildsRootPath\$year\02 - February"
Copy-Item -Path "$*BuildsRootPath\$year\$oldMonth\" -Destination "$newMonth" -recurse -Force ` I'd just need to implement the year change portion

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a followup question: post it as a new question. Make sure to include the code you currently have as well as a description of desired and actual results.

Comment: I don't feel I am moving the target, it's still the same target from the beginning.  But you did give me some where to start... and these comment chain is getting ridiculous.  Thanks..  I'll start a new thread after trying a few things that you helped with .  Thank you again.